# Does == check for full equality in Booleans? - Java

Tags: java, boolean, equals-operator

So I've heard that if I compare 2 strings with == then I will only get true back if  they both refer to the same object/instance. That's strings. What about Booleans?

Comment: How could the strings refer to the same instance and not be identical?

Comment: No, what I mean is if they are identical but *don't* refer to the same instance, == returns false.

Comment: Please read anything before posting, and don't start with I heard something somewhere.

Comment: I've heard that = I know that in the above case. Not saying you should have known that, but just clarifying.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

> Does == check for full equality in Booleans? - Java

It depends on whether you're talking about `Boolean`s (the object wrapper, note the capital `B`) or `boolean`s (the primitive, note the lower case `b`). If you're talking about `Boolean`s (the object wrapper), as with all objects, `==` checks for *identity*, not *equivalence*. If you're talking about `boolean`s (primitives), it checks for equivalence.

So:

```
Boolean a, b;
a = new Boolean(false);
b = new Boolean(false);
System.out.println("a == b? " + (a == b)); // "a == b? false", because they're not the same instance
```

But

```
boolean c, d;
c = false;
d = false;
System.out.println("c == d? " + (c == d)); // "c == d? true", because they're primitives with the same value
```

---

Regarding strings:

> I've heard that if I compare 2 strings with == then I will only get true back if the strings are identical and they both refer to the same object/instance...

It's not really an "and": `==` will **only** check whether the two `String` variables refer to the same `String` instance. Of course, one `String` instance can only have one set of contents, so if both variables point to the same instance, naturally the contents are the same... :-) The key point is that `==` will report `false` for *different* `String` instances even if they have the same characters in the same order. That's why we use `equals` on them, not `==`. Strings can get a bit confusing because of [`intern`ing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29), which is specific to strings (there's no equivalent for `Boolean`, although when you use `Boolean.valueOf(boolean)`, you'll get a cached object). Also note that Java doesn't have primitive strings like it does primitive `boolean`, `int`, etc.

Comment: So if I use `new boolean` to make my variable, as opposed to `new Boolean`, `==` will be the same as `equals()`?

Comment: @Bluefire: You don't use `new boolean` (lower case) at all. You use `true` or `false` or the result of a comparison operation. I think there are very few use cases in modern Java for `Boolean`.

Comment: So to declare a primitive boolean, do I put something like `boolean myBoolean = true`?

Comment: @Bluefire: Yup. Or `boolean myBoolean = false;` or just `boolean myBoolean;` if you don't want to initialize it under later. Primitives don't need to be constructed (so just like `int n = 5;` or just `int n;`, `boolean b = false;` or just `boolean b;`).

Comment: @Bluefire Note that evne if you really want a `Boolean` you should never call `new Boolean`, but instead use `Boolean.TRUE` respectively `Boolean.FALSE`. If you follow that rule you can actually compare them with `==` (although you probably still shouldn't).

Comment: so, by not having to re-verify all the code for if it is a primitive or wrapper, the best option is simply use `Boolean.compare(x,y)==0` everywhere right?

Comment: @AquariusPower: I've never had code where I was unsure whether I was dealing with a primitive or a wrapper.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I actually meant full code refactoring thru `sed` regex (I actually use [secRefactorInFiles.sh](http://sourceforge.net/p/scriptechocolor/git/ci/master/tree/ScriptEchoColor/bin.extras/secRefactorInFiles.sh)), so I will not be checking each, and will just test if the application still works, but I believe the application will work better by avoiding the b1==b2 confusion. Obs.: my code has standards like booleans begin with "b", so regex will work properly.

Answer (score 4):

If you have an Object use equals,
when not you can run in things like this.
(VM cache for autoboxing primitives)

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
       Boolean a = true;
       Boolean b = true;
       System.out.println(a == b);
       a = new Boolean(true);
       b = new Boolean(true);
       System.out.println(a == b);
   }
```

the output is TRUE and FALSE

Comment: this is not improving the answer, please add an answer only if it improves already submitted answers

Comment: Actually original answer lacks autoboxing example. I came across the following code: Optional<Boolean> a = f(); Optional<Boolean> b = g(); if (a.isPresent() && b.isPresent() && a.get() != b.get()) {...} which looks like a bug. The reason it is not a bug is that f() and g() were returning things like Optional.of(true), etc. and auto-boxing feature made it correct. Note, however, that for ints auto-boxing "caches" only values up-to 127 or something like this, so it is better to avoid relying on "caching".

Comment: When you use Boolean instead of boolean, you shoud init it with Boolean.TRUE or Boolean.FALSE.

Answer (score 4):

When using ( `==` ) with booleans,

1. If one of the operands is a Boolean wrapper, then it is first unboxed
   into a boolean primitive and the two are compared.
2. If both are Boolean wrappers,created with 'new' keyword, then their
   references are compared just like in the case of other objects.
   `new Boolean("true") == new Boolean("true")` is false
3. If both are Boolean wrappers,created without 'new' keyword,

   ```
   Boolean a = false;
   Boolean b = Boolean.FALSE;
   // (a==b) return true
   ```

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you are talking about value types like: `int`, `boolean`, `long` or about reference types: `Integer`, `Boolean`, `Long`. value types could be compared with `==`, reference types must be compared with `equals`.

Comment: Not always true. If you use Boolean and init it with Boolean.FALSE or Boolean.TRUE, you can make comparison with ==