# How to compare two Booleans in Java?

Tags: java

I have to compare two `Boolean` wrappers with each other. As a result I want to know if they are equal or not.

This is what I came up with:

```
public static boolean areEqual(final Boolean a, final Boolean b) {
    if (a == b) {
        return true;
    }

    if (a != null && b != null) {
        return a.booleanValue() == b.booleanValue();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Is there a better and/or shorter way to correctly compare two `Boolean` wrappers for equality?

First I wanted to use `Object.equals()` or `Boolean.compareTo()` but both ways could end up in a `NullPointerException`, right?
Maybe there is something that I don't see here, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: You're better off writing code such that your booleans _can't_ be null (or if they are, your code fails and NPEs out, since that would be a bug). Then you can compare them with equals like a sane person.

Comment: Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31366231/how-to-check-if-two-boolean-values-are-equal)

Comment: @pvg I have to use Boolean wrappers, that's the problem.

Comment: @Laf your linked answer just takes care of two primitive booleans.

Comment: @winklerrr that's fine. What I'm suggesting is you enforce non-nullness once, someplace. The `java.util.Objects` approach works fine but you want to use that sparingly because you're essentially peppering your code with implicit null checks making it harder to determine the root cause of possibly invalid state. If you enforce (at the relevant abstraction barrier/interface) non-nullness, you don't have to worry about it again. An NPE just tells you you have a bug, rather than hiding it with null checks.

Comment: Could the downvoters please explain why?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The shortest you can get, with null safety (works naturally for any other objects that implement `equals()`):

```
java.util.Objects.equals(a, b);
```

Comment: Indeed the best answer here, when one of the value goes NULL, result will be false which is what OP is obviously looking for.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you. Finally someone who reads the question carefully.

Comment: Found a good [article on the web](https://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2010/04/java-7-the-new-java-util-objects-class.html) about this exact new feature in Java7

Comment: @winklerrr You had this in your question-why not just try it next time?

Comment: @DaveNewton he was referring to `Object.equals()`, not `Objects.equals()`.

Comment: @Kayaman Ah, I see, missed that.

Comment: @DaveNewton I can't see what you are talking about? I mentioned `Object.equals()` and not `Objects.equals()` (pay attention on the `s` at the end of `objects`. This makes a difference.)

Comment: @winklerrr Yes, that's what Kayaman said, and why I said "Ah, I see, missed that".

Comment: @DaveNewton sorry, for that! You both already replied while I was still typing.

Comment: @winklerrr No worries

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for you to reinvent the wheel.

If you are using Java 7 or later, use the `java.util.Objects` class (as mentioned by Kayaman).

If you are using an earlier version of java, use the Apache BooleanUtils class.
Try a google search for "apache booleanutils" to find out how to get it.

Edit: corrected java version.

Comment: If I would use an earlier version than Java 7, I would mark your answer as the correct one, because it covers more scenarios.

Answer (score -1):

It is working for me.

```
 public class MyClass {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Boolean x=true;
    Boolean y=true;
    System.out.println(compare(x,y)); // true
    x=false;
    y=true;
    System.out.println(compare(x,y)); // false
    x=true;
    y=false;
    System.out.println(compare(x,y)); // false
    x=false;
    y=false;
    System.out.println(compare(x,y)); // true
    x=null;
    y=null;
    System.out.println(compare(x,y)); // true
  }
  public static boolean compare(final Boolean a, final Boolean b) {
    if (a == null || b == null) {
      return a == b;
    }
    return a.equals(b);
  }
}
```

Probe with https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler

Edit: add exception to null values.

Comment: It's working because you use the primitive booleans and not their wrappers. You have to pay attention on `b` vs `B`: `boolean` vs `Boolean`

Comment: Casting can be easily done with `Boolean.booleanValue()`, I know, but this still throws a `NullPointerException` and therefore needs more than the actual cast.

Comment: Yes in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728616/boolean-vs-boolean-in-java

Comment: Did you even read what you linked? Your linked answer has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: Has the explain of difference between to types.

Comment: Yeah, but I didn't ask about the difference between `boolean` and `Boolean`. Please read the question again.