# Cannot invoke isEqualTo(boolean) on the primitive type boolean

Tags: java, junit, junit4

This code needs to be tested but I'm not able to resolve the error.
Boolean isValid is the method which needs to be tested.

```
 public boolean isValid(String email) 
    { 
        String emailRegex = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_+&*-]+(?:\\."+ 
                            "[a-zA-Z0-9_+&*-]+)*@" + 
                            "(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.)+[a-z" + 
                            "A-Z]{2,7}$"; 
                              
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(emailRegex); 
        if (email == null) 
            return false; 
        return pat.matcher(email).matches(); 
    } 

Getting error in writing test case: Cannot invoke isEqualTo(boolean) on the primitive type boolean
@Test
    public void isValidTest() {
        Validation v = new Validation();
        String email = "bhavya@gmail.com";
        assertEquals(v.isValid(email).isEqualTo(true)); //this line gives the error.
    }
```

Comment: There are no methods for primitive types. Just use `assertTrue(v.isValid(email))`.

Comment: Check this post for an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31366231/how-to-check-if-two-boolean-values-are-equal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> assertEquals(v.isValid(email).isEqualTo(true);
> ```

This line is wrong in so many ways.

1. The parentheses don't even line up.
2. The `isEqualTo` thing does not start with `assertEquals` - it starts with `assertThat`. You're mixing two completely different ways to write tests.
3. Because of the missing parens, you are now attempting to invoke `.isEqualTo` on a primitive boolean. It's not an object, `primitiveExpression.anything` doesn't work in java.

You presumably want either:

```
assertThat(v.isValid(email)).isEqualTo(true);
```

or more likely:

```
assertTrue(v.isValid(email));
```

Comment: assertThat code is also not working. AssertTrue worked. 
Thank you :)

Comment: `assertThat(v.isValid(email)).isTrue();`

Answer (score 1):

//you can try is it with assertTrue and pass the value type return by isValid()

```
@Test
public void isValidTest() {
   Validation v = new Validation();
   String email = "bhavya@gmail.com";
   Boolean value = v.isValid(email);
   assertTrue(value); 
}
```