# Java Boolean equality

Tags: java, boolean

In Java Boolean.TRUE method has following implementation

```
 /**
 * The {@code Boolean} object corresponding to the primitive
 * value {@code true}.
 */
public static final Boolean TRUE = new Boolean(true);
```

and now:

```
System.out.println(new Boolean(true) == new Boolean(true));
System.out.println(Boolean.TRUE == Boolean.TRUE);
```

prints:

```
false
true
```

WHY ?!

Comment: A `static` field is initialized once, not on each access.

Comment: `new Boolean(true) == new Boolean(true)` is comparing objects, not their contents.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072870/does-check-for-full-equality-in-booleans-java

Comment: @user109447 - did you try my solution? If it worked then please accept the answer and vote up!

Answer (score 2):

`Boolean.TRUE` is not a method but a member variable declaration.

```
public static final Boolean TRUE = new Boolean(true);
```

Whenever you use `new` operator it creates a new instance and operator `==` compares instance references and not their content (`equals` compares contents) which means below is comparing two different instance references and not their contents, hence its `false`.

```
new Boolean(true) == new Boolean(true)
```

As `Boolean.TRUE` is static for `Boolean` wrapper class, below means you are comparing same static variable (not their content but actual instance reference), hence its `true`.

```
Boolean.TRUE == Boolean.TRUE
```